# Logging to IIS log file from asmx service - C#

Tags: c#, logging, iis, httpresponse, asmx

I'm working on an asmx web service. I'm trying to append to IIS log file programmatically using C#.
Log file is created by IIS on daily basis. Installed Nuget package in solution - Microsoft.Web.Administration - v7.0. IIS Server Version 10. I tried following 2 approaches.
Please suggest me. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.
Sample code as below,

````
           var serverManager = new ServerManager();

           string path = string.Empty;
           string fullPath = string.Empty;
           string logFile = string.Empty;

           foreach (var site in serverManager.Sites) 
           {
               path = System.IO.Path.Combine(site.LogFile.Directory);
               DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);

               foreach (var dir in directory.GetDirectories()) 
               {
                   if (dir.ToString() == "W3SV") {
                       logFile = dir.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(f => f.Name).FirstOrDefault().ToString(); 
                   
                   }
               
               }
           }

           fullPath = path + @"\W3SV\" + logFile;

           try {

               TextWriter tw = File.CreateText(fullPath);
               HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse(tw);
               response.AppendToLog("Add to Log file");
               tw.Flush();
               tw.Close();
           }
           catch (Exception ex) { }```


**Another approach I tried,**

try{
Http.Context.Current.Response.AppendToLog("Append to Log");
}
````

Answer (score 0):

The files in the w3sv folder is for http request logging and is owned by IIS. Their purpose is to contain logs with one line per request in a standardized format which is useful in a more generalistic approach to analyzing application health by means of http status code distribution, time taken per request etc. Modifying this file to contain regular operations log would confuse many existing tools and server administrators and I would consider it a bad idea.

You would probably benefit from logging the more application specific logs to files located elsewhere. If you need to establish a connection between the requests and the log messages in this other file, you could introduce a correlation id linking the message to the request.